# Clojure: Append vector of strings to string resulting in a vector

Tags: clojure

new at clojure so this will probably be an easy one.

I have a vector of strings, lets call them `names` and pretend it contains:
 `["Jake" "Phil" "Bob"]`

I want to append these strings to the end of another string called `intro`, which contains:
`"My name is "`

and I want to put the results into a vector so that it is:

`["My name is Jake" "My name is Phil" "My name is Bob"]`

I've tried several combinations using the `map` function but they all seem to break apart the `intro` string. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either don't map over the intro string

```
(mapv #(str "My name is " %) ["Jake" "Phil" "Bob"])
;=> ["My name is Jake" "My name is Phil" "My name is Bob"]

(vec (for [name ["Jake" "Phil" "Bob"]] (str "My name is " name)))
;=> ["My name is Jake" "My name is Phil" "My name is Bob"]
```

Or, repeat the intro string

```
(mapv str (repeat "My name is ") ["Jake" "Phil" "Bob"])
;=> ["My name is Jake" "My name is Phil" "My name is Bob"]
```

Comment: Awesome. I did not know about mapv. Three very understandable ways to do the same think. Any insight about which one is most efficient? I would assume its the first one.

Comment: @JakeSchwartz You could develop a benchmark with Criterium's help, but yes, it ought to be the first with just a closure and mapv. Usually, you shouldn't care.